# Unknown SQLCODE values

Tags: sql, database, db2, sqlcode

I've had some problems with my database monitoring tool, Ignite. It fails to start because it gets an error for certain queries that it tries to do, this is an example:

```
SELECT CAST(stmt_text AS BLOB) igniteex, num_executions, num_compilations, rows_read, rows_written, stmt_sorts 
FROM table(snapshot_dyn_sql('[db_name]',-2)) AS sntable
```

This query (and the others, which are much longer) works just fine (and are very fast) when I execute it from my database analyzing tool (Aqua Data Studio). Ignite however reports an SQLException with SQLCODE values that are not listed (for example [here](http://www.caliberdt.com/tips/sqlcode.htm)).

The database is IBM DB2 9.7. The SQLCODE values returned are -930, -954, -443, which seems to be not listed anywhere. Does anyone know what these SQLCODE values mean?

Comment: May be you should reference the product documentation for error codes, instead of some random internet page. Look for [SQL0930N, SQL0954N, SQL0443N respectively](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/rsqlmsg.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F5-6-27&lang=en).

Comment: Well I was looking at [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/db2z_n.dita), but since it didn't include the codes I needed and also I thought it was hard to navigate, I preferred the link I posted.

Thanks for pointing me to the correct section!

Comment: @MatsRydberg, the page you were looking at is for DB2 for z/OS.  While many things are the same between DB2 on z/OS, LUW, and IBM i.  There are many differences also.  Best to stick with the docs for your platform and version.

Comment: A shortcut to the info is to ask db2. From a sh you can do db2 "? SQL930" and get info about the error.

Comment: You can even get the info from Aqua: `VALUES (SYSPROC.SQLERRM ('SQL930', '', '', 'en_US', 0))`

Comment: Thanks! I'll summarize your tips in an answer and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct documentation for this is [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/rsqlmsg.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F5-6-27&lang=en).

[SQLCODE -443](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00443n.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-6-27-0-285&lang=en) means a DB2 routine returns an error.

SQLCODE -930 means that there is not enough storage available. This storage is not in terms of disk space or total memory, but seems to be concerned with allocated memory for the database manager.

SQLCODE -954 means basically the same as -930; but it says all memory is used rather than "not enough for this task".

Anyway, restarting the db2 server did remove these errors.

Comment: I can't put links to the other two codes due to low reputation. They are here as [-930](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00930n.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-6-27-1-192&lang=en) and [-954](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00954c.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-6-27-1-198&lang=en) instead.